# What is the characteristic of $\mathbb{Z_4}\times\mathbb{Z_6}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I show the characteristic is the $lcm$ of $4$ and $6$.

> Suppose we have a ring $\mathbb{Z_a}\times\mathbb{Z_b}$.
>
> Let $(1, 1) \in \mathbb{Z_4}\times\mathbb{Z_6}$ (since it's an identity).
>
> Then for some $k$, we have $k(1, 1) = (k, k) = 0$.
>
> Thus $k = 0 \mod a$ and $k = 0 \mod b$.

Up to this step I have shown that $a, b | k$. Now I need to show that $k | a$ and $k | b$. Thus, we have $ke = a$ and $kf = b$ for some $e, f \in \mathbb{Z}$. But I don't think this leads to anywhere. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to show $k\mid a$ and $k\mid b$. You know that $a\mid k$ and $b\mid k$ so that $m = lcm(a,b)\mid k$. Now show that $m(1,1) = 0$, so $m$ is the smallest number satisfying that property.

Comment: How can I show $m(1, 1) = 0$? Just say $m = 0 \mod a$ and $m = 0 \mod b$ so $m$ is the characteristic of the ring?

Comment: No. If $m = 0\pmod{a}$ and $m = 0\pmod{b}$, then $m(1,1) = 0$, so the characteristic divides $m$. Between that and what you already have, it must equal m

Comment: That's what I just said? I'm confused